# Ansible: Copy file from path in Environment Variable

Tags: ansible

I'd like to copy a file from local to remote using Ansible with the `copy` module. It fails because it cannot find the file.

I've tried both relative paths (from the Ansible root) as well as with environment variables (which would be the preferred way).

I think Ansible isn't supporting ENV, at least it cannot find the file. This is how I've done it:

```
- name: Ensure test file
  copy:
    src: $DNM_TOOLS_HOME/ch/testfile.txt
    dest: /tmp/testfile.txt
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
```

Is there a way I can make use of Environment variables? If not, from which folder is Ansible doing the relative path lookup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yaml](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/) does not interpolate environment variables as you are trying to do, nor ansible which uses [jinja2 templating](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_templating.html).

In this case, you will have to use an [ansible lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_lookups.html), more specifically the [env lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/env.html)

```
src: "{{ lookup('env', 'DNM_TOOLS_HOME') }}/ch/testfile.txt"
```

Note that lookup always run on the controler machine. If you ever need to get an environment variable from a remote host inside a task, those are available in the `ansible_env` hash (e.g. `some_yaml_key: "{{ ansible_env.MY_REMOTE_ENV_VAR }}"`